# MFC: Dialog ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) shows old content before WM_PAINT?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a MFC dialog with a graphic displayed that is updated via `OnPaint()`.  The dialog continues to exist but it is hidden with `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` then later open again with `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` but there is a moment when the old contents are shown before `OnPaint()` updates the new graphic.   I got around it by first `ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE)` followed by `ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL)` but why?  How can I just ensure when the window is shown it calls `OnPaint()` before it puts back the old device context graphic?

TIA!!

Comment: Minimize your code to the Max and show it us. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'd try an `InvalidateRect(TRUE)` before the `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)`...